# How can I push an object in a nested array in mongoDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
    comment: req.body.comment,
        image: req.body.image,
        creatorId: req.userData.userId,
        postId: req.query.postId,
        creatorPic: userProfilePic,
        creatorNickname: userNickname,
        date: Date.now()
    });
    Post.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: req.query.postId,
            'comments._id': req.query.commentId,
        },
        {
            $push: {
                'comments' : replier
            }
        },
        {new: true},
        (error, post) => {
            if(error){
                console.log(error)
            } 
            return res.status(200).json({
                post
            })
        }
```

So I have an array of posts, where each post has its comments array every comment has its id and they have replies array. How can I push the reply in that comments array? I'm new in backend and I don't have a good understanding of mongoDb or mongoose.

Comment: Can you give me some example or explain in brief what you wanted to achieve?@Mishka

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So imagine an array of posts, in which every post has its own comments array, where we have objects of comments. We should be able to reply on the comments, right? so we need replies array, in every comment object is replies array. and when I write a reply to a comment, i want to find an id of the post where that comment is, reach the comments array in that post object and find the comment id on which i want to reply. Then I just want to push that reply object in that found comment's "replies" array. I'm new and don't know how to do It.

Comment: You could do something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UYlQezP3-dE "Click me!").